# jQuery: sticking footer needs window resize to work sometimes

Tags: jquery, sticky-footer

I'm using a simple [**jQuery** plugin](http://www.drupalcoder.com/blog/cross-browser-sticky-footer-with-fluid-height-using-jquery.html) to sticking footer to the bottom of page, It works fine except when I put a table in the page:
[image: screenshot]
But when I resize the page, it gets fixed and footer sticks to the bottom. What's wrongwith it? Is it a **CSS** related problem or **jQuery** problem?

You can view the page without table [here](http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/jA73A/) and page with table [here](http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/GSjtK/).

It's the **jQuery** script for sticking footer the bottom of page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    positionFooter();

    $(window)
        .scroll(positionFooter)
        .resize(positionFooter);

    function positionFooter() {
        var docHeight = $(document.body).height() - $("#sticky-footer-push").height();
        if (docHeight < $(window).height()) {
            var diff = $(window).height() - docHeight;
            if (!$("#sticky-footer-push").length > 0) {
                $("#footer").before('<div id="sticky-footer-push"></div>');
            }
            $("#sticky-footer-push").height(diff);
        }
    }
});

$(window).load(function () {
    $("#footer").stickyFooter();
});

// sticky footer plugin
(function ($) {
    var footer;

    $.fn.extend({
        stickyFooter: function (options) {
            footer = this;

            positionFooter();

            $(window)
                .scroll(positionFooter)
                .resize(positionFooter);

            function positionFooter() {
                var docHeight = $(document.body).height() - $("#sticky-footer-push").height();
                if (docHeight < $(window).height()) {
                    var diff = $(window).height() - docHeight;
                    if (!$("#sticky-footer-push").length > 0) {
                        $(footer).before('<div id="sticky-footer-push"></div>');
                    }
                    $("#sticky-footer-push").height(diff);
                }
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line just below the content div:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Your Code look like:

```
<div id="content">
    //HERE is your table
    <hr />
    <p>categories:</p>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but why it happens and how did you know the solution?

Comment: It happens because sometimes div have to be clear so that next div will be start just after that. and vast experience of jquery use thats why i catched your problem quickly and give you solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a CSS problem instead of a jQuery problem...
Try adding this CSS to your stylesheet (not tested):

```
html, body
{
    min-height: 100%;
}
```